# What is uiconfid in kaltura configuration

Tags: kaltura

Where do I get my `uiconfid`, is it from my account?
Generally what is `uiconfid` in layman terms?

> The uiConf ID is used to reference the player instance you wish to
>   render when embedding a video in your pages or app views.][1](https://vpaas.kaltura.com/thank-you.php#uiconfid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI Conf holds the player configuration. UI Confs are created automatically when you add new player in the KMC (Kaltura Management Console).

To get a UI Conf ID:

1. Login to KMC
2. Go to **Studio** > **Universal Studio** or **TV Platform Studio**

The Player ID that you see in those tables is the UI Conf ID.

Comment: Thanks, what is the purpose of it?

Comment: It is the ID which refers the player created in the KMC console.